# How to subtract one text cell from another in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have two text cells in Excel as shown below which contains strings (A1 and A2), I am trying to remove A2 cell characters from A1 cell string and store the result in A3.

[image]

I have tried using few functions like SEARCH(), TEXT(), RIGHT() .. but couldnt achieve what I would need as result.

I could do this easily using any programming language (Python, C, etc.,) - just need a loop and couple of string functions. But couldn't figure out the way to get the same using Excel Formula.

Any thoughts how can we get this?

Comment: This is to be case sensitive? (You took out `i`, but left `I`).  You're probably going to need VBA, is it *required* to use formulas? You could do a super convoluted `Substitute` where you wrap it inside a substitute, inside a substitute...

Comment: It might not be true but from what I know you can't do it by a simple built-in function. You need to use a vba macro

Comment: probably write an Excel VBA function.

Comment: Do you always know the length of A2? you could nest a series of "Substitute()" if you have to avoid vba, but the best option like others have said would be a vba UDF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing this via a UDF would be pretty straightforward. Basically just loop through the `ins` character by character and use `replace()` to swap the character out with nothing;

```
Function textSubtract(startString As String, subtractString As String) As String
    'Function to subtract characters in one string from another string

    'Loop through every character in subtractString
    Dim charCounter As Integer
    For charCounter = 1 To Len(subtractString)

        'Replace out the character in startString
        startString = Replace(startString, Mid(subtractString, charCounter, 1), "")

    Next charCounter

    'Return
    textSubtract = startString

End Function
```

Then you can call it like:

[image]

Comment: Why not add an optional boolean parameter that turns case-sensitivity on and off? (defaulted to on as per the OP's sample)

Comment: It's VBA... The sky is the limit and I was just writing to spec.

Answer (score 5):

In **B2** enter:

```
=MID($A$2,COLUMN()-1,1)
```

and copy across *(this isolates the characters)*.  In **B3** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE($A$1,B2,"")
```

In **C3** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B3,C2,"")
```

and copy across *(this removes each character)*:

[image]

Comment: I figure there's no way, via formula, to do all that in one cell? Since you'd somehow have to iterate through `A2`, yeah?

Comment: unless you want to nest it out to 10 places if you knew the limit of characters in a2 was 10

Comment: @BruceWayne It is probably possible to do it with a single ***Array Formula***, but that is beyond my ability.

Comment: If there is an array formula it is beyond me, too. You can use an array to iterate through the second cells characters, but as it is always referring to the first string and not itself only the last letter substitution will show.  But I am still learning, so maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @ScottCraner  **It would be of great interest to me if you succeed** !

Comment: I was kind of hoping that someone would read my comment and say, "Hey, Dummy, all you have to do is ..."

Answer (score 0):

If case sensitive replacement is okay, then `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"")` will replace the instances of B1 in A1 in the current cell.